# kinetic energy in photoelectric effect

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, thought-experiment

the formula of kinetic energy in photoelectric effect is given by 
$$K = h\nu - w$$
where $K$ is kinetic energy of released electron, $\nu$ is frequency of light and $w$ is work needed to release electron from matter.
I wonder why it is not
$$K= nh\nu -w  ??$$
that is why electron cannot absorb more than one photon to be released ?!
thanks.

Comment: You may need to rephrase your question. What does n represent? The photo electric effect involves one photon for one ejected electron. The frequency of the photon determines the speed or kinetic energy of the electron.

Comment: I think maybe one photon don't have enough energy to release the an electron but two (for example) photons  have this energy. that is $$h\nu<w<2h\nu$$.then if two photons strike with one electron then it release with kinetic energy $2h\nu-w$ @BillAlsept

Comment: it has already been established that one photon with high enough frequency will reject one electron. You do not need two photons at all.

Comment: It has also been established that the intensity or number of photons has no effect on the number of ejected photons IF the frequencies are too low.

Comment: thanks. but for example observation says ejection don't happen for very low frequencies.
 but my (wrong!) vision says i can lower frequency of light to half (so that one photon have no enough energy to eject an electron) and yet electrons release by absorbing two photon. what is wrong with my vision and what theory says to it. thanks. @BillAlsept

Comment: If it worked like that then higher intensity would eject more electrons But it doesn't work like that.